# How to set default image if image not exist in s3 using VUE JS

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js, error-handling

Im fetching an image from S3 bucket and display it using VUEJS. Im encountering some difficulties like how to display a default image if the image is not existing in S3 bucket.

The  is for text but how can I achieve this with default image?

Here is my code

```
<template>
<div id="book_cover"><sui-image :src="bookCover" @error="imageLoadOnError"></sui-image></div>
<template>

<script>
export default {
   methods:{
       imageLoadOnError(e) {
          e.target.src = "alternative-image-if-not-exist"
      }
   },
   computed:{
   bookCover(){
        if(this.book){
            return this.book.book_cover =  "fetched-image-url.jpg"
        }
   }
}
</script>
```

The output still error and displaying broken images. How will I achieve this? Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would assume your code would work with `<img>`, but my guess is your code is not compatible with `<sui-image>` (whatever that is).

Try changing `bookCover` to the alternative image, but since it's a computed property it cannot be modified so you will need to change it to a simple `data` property instead.

Or if you must have the computed property, try something like:

```js
data() {
  return {
    error: false
  }
},
methods: {
  imageLoadOnError() {
    this.error = true
  }
},
computed: {
  bookCover() {
    // If there is an error use the alt image, otherwise if there
    // is a book then use the book image, otherwise use something else
    return this.error
      ? 'alt-image'
      : this.book
        ? this.book.book_cover
        : 'placeholder-image'

    // Alternatively
    if (this.error) {
      return 'alt-image';
    } else if (this.book) {
      return this.book.book_cover;
    } else {
      return 'something-else';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your codes sir but still not working. I also tried to change the  <sui-image> to normal <img> tag and it works. <sui-image > is Semantic UI for responsiveness of designs. Thankyou for your anser appreciate it!

Comment: Ok, I just checked the [source code](https://github.com/Semantic-UI-Vue/Semantic-UI-Vue/blob/master/src/elements/Image/Image.jsx) for Semantic UI Image component and it doesn't support the `error` event, so you're out of luck using that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [vue-progressive-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-progressive-image).

Your code should look like the following if you're using it:

```
<div id="book_cover">
   <progressive-img 
     :src="bookCover"
     :fallback="fallbackImage"
   />
</div>
```

It will be painful if you're going to deal with onError event of every images. You can set placeholders for optimization with this npm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mixin for every image load error. and it's work.

```
//On mixin create a method
handleImageError(event) 
{
    event.target.src = "default-image.jpg";
}

//on image source 
<img :src="image" @error="handleImageError($event)">
```